# Open New Email with HTML body from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am trying to implement a web feature in ASP.NET C# where the user clicks an image on a webpage and starts a new Outlook email message with some HTML from the page copied to the body section. The section that is emailed would contain text, images and links.

I already looked at mailto, but it does not work because the &body= does not accept HTML content and only renders it as plain text. I do not want the email to actually get sent, as the user determines who receives the email along with other relevant information.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Update: I've already taken a look at other similar questions and the solutions either involve actually sending the emails or involve solutions not related to ASP.NET (ex. using PHP).

Comment: Yes. [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Is this for an internal corporate environment running IE? If so I can give an example that requires the site to be full trust and uses outlook automation and JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidEwen Yes it is actually. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @AugPopa I have restated the question and added an answer here [Open new email in outlook with html body from IE web site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509994/open-new-email-in-outlook-with-html-body-from-ie-web-site).