# Open new email in outlook with html body from IE web site

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, email, outlook

I am working in a corporate environment on an internal use web application and have a requirement to generate an email in the users Outlook retaining their signature so that they can then modify if required and send it themselves.

All users are on IE8+ and the site is a part of Trusted Sites with ActiveX objects enabled so I was hoping to use outlook automation to achieve this.

Here is a quick summary of my requirements to differentiate this from existing questions.

- Only needs to support IE8+ and Outlook
- HTML body formatting support
- Attachment support
- Must retain the users configured signature

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be achieved using JavaScript in IE if the site is a Trusted Site and ActiveX objects are enabled. I have had this script work as far back as IE6 and tested up to IE10 I am unsure about its support in IE11.

An important point about the script below is that you must call `Display` on the email before trying to extract the signature from it or trying to set its `HTMLBody` otherwise you will lose the signature information.

```
try {

    //get outlook and create new email
    var outlook = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application');
    var email = outlook.CreateItem(0);

    //add some recipients
    email.Recipients.Add('user1@company.com').Type = 1; //1=To
    email.Recipients.Add('user2@company.com').Type = 2; //2=CC

    //subject and attachments
    email.Subject = 'A Subject';
    //email.Attachments.Add('URL_TO_FILE', 1); //1=Add by value so outlook downloads the file from the url

    // display the email (this will make the signature load so it can be extracted)
    email.Display();

    //use a regular expression to extract the html before and after the signature
    var signatureExtractionExpression = new RegExp('/[^~]*(<BODY[^>]*>)([^~]*</BODY>)[^~]*/', 'i');
    signatureExtractionExpression.exec(email.HTMLBody);
    var beforeSignature = RegExp.$1;
    var signature = RegExp.$2;

    //set the html body of the email
    email.HTMLBody = beforeSignature + '<h1>Our Custom Body</h1>' + signature;

} catch(ex) {
    //something went wrong
}
```

Comment: It worked for me too. I only had to enable the 'Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe.' option in the IE security options.

Comment: giving an error. `Outlook not starting` If outlook is running before the button clicked, it giving error too. `Two instance of outlook is not running at the same time.` So I don't know how to open compose mail window.

Comment: hey guys, is there any way to include an image in the body of the email using this method? I am using this in IE11 to create a report and currently require people to copy and paste an image into the body - can this be done through just javascript?