# (successfully) Attach file to a Mailto link? [Not duplicate]

Tags: javascript, email, mailto

I am working on a service called Fon2Scratch, and I’m working on the part where the user uploads the file, and sends it to me.

I have tried many methods such as:

```
window.open('mailto:myEmail@service.com?subject=Fon2Scratch Upload&body=File is ' + File.name + '&attach=' + File);
window.open('mailto:myEmail@service.com?subject=Fon2Scratch Upload&body=File is ' + File.name + '&attachment=' + File);
window.open('mailto:myEmail@service.com?subject=Fon2Scratch Upload&body=File is ' + File.name + '&attachments=' + File);
```

None of these methods worked. How does one get an attachment on a mailto preset?

Edit: the `File` part is

```
HTML:

<input type="file" accept="font/ttf, font/otf, font/eoff, font/woff, font/svg, font/woff2" id="file">

JS:

const File = document.getElementById("file");
```

If this isn’t possible, then just tell me how to get JavaScript ID elements into NodeJS.

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot attach files when using a simple `mailto:` link. To do what you're asking you'll need to create and send the email from the server side - either your local instance, or a third party via an API.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not entirely true. It's not a simple mailto link, but you can construct a .EML file encode your attachment within the file. Clients can then download this file and open it in their preferred email client. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699855/4698546 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120017/is-there-a-way-to-add-attachments-to-an-eml-file-created-in-javascript-or-other

Comment: That's not sending a file directly via clicking a button though, is it? It's also janky as hell, and flags security concerns in modern browsers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, but neither is "mailto". This requires multiple clicks instead of one, but if you're looking for a solution that avoids running your own server to send emails, this may be a potential option.

Comment: That's a fair point, however the security flags will be a blocker for almost all use cases.