# Generate long e-mail body for MS Outlook with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, email, outlook

I need to generate an e-mail template from the web application and then open user e-mail client populated with that template.
The most common way to do that is to use mailto: protocol

```
const mailtoLink = 
  'mailto:' + email +
  '?subject=' + subject +
  '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(emailBody);
```

But I have to use a plenty of cyrillic symbols in the body, thus my encoded link exceeds 2500 characters, and client app just won't open when clicking such a link (in my case maximum length that works is 2044 symbols)

The other solution I've come to is generating an .eml file and making user to download/open it, using approach of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951843/use-javascript-to-create-an-html-email-in-microsoft-outlook) thread, but it has encoding issues and lowers the overall user experience.

Are there any other ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: I don't think so. But you might want to consider alternatives like a) sending the email through your own server, not using the user's email client b) writing an email client add-on instead of a web application

Comment: Wat are the encoding issues with the EML file?

Answer (score 0):

Generating .eml files is a universal solution. Also, you may consider automating Outlook from a web browser. But in this scenario, you can do that from Internet Explorer (i.e. on Windows only). See [Compose and Send E-mail from JavaScript by using Outlook Automation 2007](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rajnishkaushik/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007/) for more information.

Please remember that EML and MSG file formats are well-described. For example, see [Outlook Item (.msg) File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82).