# Image Size Reduced when Base64Encoded Image is embedded in rich email containing html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working on code to generate rich text html as mail content as eml file.

I have followed below link:

https://jsfiddle.net/seanodotcom/yd1n8Lfh/

The JsFiddler to replicate this issue is :
https://jsfiddle.net/AnitaSS/g7jnvuab/1

Code:

```
<script>
(function () {
debugger

var textFile = null,
  makeTextFile = function (text) {
  debugger
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
    if (textFile !== null) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(data, 'message.eml');
    } else {
    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    link.href = textFile;
    link.click();   
    }   
  };

  var create = document.getElementById('create'),
    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
  create.addEventListener('click', function () {
     makeTextFile(textbox.value);
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```

So far my html does render and eml file is downloaded.

However, issue is that I have a base 64 encoded image in my html which get reduced in size when eml file is generated.

Below is screen shot of eml file and html.
[image: html]
[image: eml]

Please suggest any inputs to fix this.