# Open .msg file from a server with link in Angular app

Tags: angular, spring-boot, outlook

I've been looking for a way to open an email in Outlook with a formatted body.
The body contains a table and images.

With `mailto` I did not find a solution, so I wonder if it is possible to download the .msg template file from my Spring Boot backend, and open it with Outlook.

This has to be done with a link in an angular app and needs to be compatible on Edge and Chrome.
If it's not possible to open the email directly, then at least downloading it as a .msg file would provide a solution.

Here is what I found for spring boot:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/trnMiniDataRefreshTemplate", produces = "application/vnd.ms-outlook")
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getFile() throws IOException {

        InputStream in = getClass()
             .getResourceAsStream("/path/to/your/email_template.msg");
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);

    }
```

But how do I convert this to a .msg file on Angular side?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951843/use-javascript-to-create-an-html-email-in-microsoft-outlook/27952099#27952099

Comment: Dmitry, does that eml format keep table structures and png images too?

Comment: Of course, the HTML body can contain any formatting, this is not any different from a regular Outlook message.