# mail body html formatted in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, outlook

```
var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");     
var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0);
theMailItem.To = to;
theMailItem.Subject = (subject);
theMailItem.CC = carbon;
theMailItem.Body = (msg);    
theMailItem.display();
```

I'm using the above javascript code to send emails through outlook everything works fine except the mail's body which isn't HTML formatted, could anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509994/open-new-email-in-outlook-with-html-body-from-ie-web-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the plain text `Body` property, set the `HTMLBody` property to a properly formatted HTML string.